# fancy tree jquery how selected automatically when use lazyloading function and when use ajax

Tags: jquery, fancytree

fancy tree jquery how selected automatically when use lazyloading function and when use ajax.here is
problem is when i,m give subGroups in lazyloading function must be selected but not selected. i,m want function select run automatically or when add in tree,selected automatically
my code :

```
lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
      console.log('lazyLoad function')
      console.log(data)
      var is_filter = false
      @if(isset($is_filter) && $is_filter)
        is_filter = true
      @endif
      var node = data.node
  // Issue an Ajax request to load child nodes
      data.result = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{secure_route('backend.products.group_items_child')}}",
        data: {
            key: node.key, is_filter: is_filter
            // key: node.key, is_filter: is_filter,selected:true????
      }
  }
}
```

and complete code is :

```
$('#group_item_modal_tree').fancytree({
  selectMode:3,
  @if(isset($is_filter))
  checkbox: function (event, data) {
    return true
  },
  @else
  checkbox: function (event, data) {
    return data.node.isFolder() ? false : true
  },
  @endif
  select: function (event, data) {
      console.log('select function')
      console.log(data)
    data.node.toggleExpanded();
    if (data.targetType === 'checkbox') {
      product_selected = []
      if (data.node.isSelected()) {
        var type = ''
          @if(isset($is_filter))
          if (data.node.key > 0) {
            type = 'type: '
          } else {
            type = 'kind: '
          }
          @endif
        product_selected['id'] = data.node.data.id
        product_selected['title'] = type + data.node.title
        product_selected['code'] = data.node.data.code
        window.jspanel_selected.push(product_selected)
      }
    }
  },
rtl: true,
source: source_data,
lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
      console.log('lazyLoad function')
      console.log(data)
      var is_filter = false
      @if(isset($is_filter) && $is_filter)
        is_filter = true
      @endif
      var node = data.node
  // Issue an Ajax request to load child nodes
      data.result = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{secure_route('backend.products.group_items_child')}}",
        data: {
            key: node.key, is_filter: is_filter
      }
  }
}
```

})

Answer (score 1):

myProblem solved with loadChildren function

```
loadChildren: function(event, data) {
    // Apply parent's state to new child nodes:
    console.log('children load')
    data.node.fixSelection3AfterClick();
},
```